# Different Terraform plan for specific environments

Tags: jenkins, terraform, jenkins-pipeline, terraform-provider-aws

I need to pass to Terraform apply specific environment variables like dev, prod, staging from *.tfstate file. So far what I did is to create 3 Workspaces and variables for them. In the variables.tf file I have:

My folder structure is:

```
dev.tfvars
prod.tfvars
staging.tfvars
main.tf
variables.tf
```

variables.tf

```
variable "env_dev" {
  type    = string
}

variable "env_prod" {
  type    = string
}

variable "env_staging" {
  type    = string
}
```

In *.tfvars for dev, prod and staging I have:

```
env_dev = "dev"
```

```
env_prod = "prod"
```

```
env_staging = "staging"
```

What I want to achieve is to update lambda aliases for the specific environment not all at the same time:

```
resource "aws_lambda_alias" "prod_lambda_alias" {
  name     = var.env_dev
  description      = "Release candidate -"
  function_name    = var.function_name
  function_version = aws_lambda_function.payload.version
}

resource "aws_lambda_alias" "dev_lambda_alias" {
  name             = var.env_dev
  description      = "Release candidate - "
  function_name    = var.function_name
  function_version = var.function_version != "" ? var.function_version : "$LATEST"
}

resource "aws_lambda_alias" "staging_lambda_alias" {
  name             = var.env_staging
  description      = "Release candidate - "
  function_name    = var.function_name
  function_version = aws_lambda_function.payload.version
}
```

And for the pipeline to use export for the specific workspace, below is for dev:

```
export TF_WORKSPACE=dev
```

Then to use Terraform apply as below to apply the changes:

```
terraform apply plan.out
```

I want to apply the changes just for specific resource. Example: If I want to update dev "resource aws_lambda_alias" "dev_lambda_alias" to update just that one and not the other 2 resources for prod and staging.

Regards

Comment: Ok. So what is you issue or question? You haven't explained what's wrong.

Comment: My question is how to apply the changes only for one of the resources (lambda alias) and don't apply it for the other 2 resources. Example: If I run terraform apply to apply the changes just for dev, not staging or prod.

Comment: If you have TF workspaces, you should have only one `aws_lambda_alias` in your TF code, not three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the name of the alias is going to have the same name as the workspace, this should do the trick:

```
resource "aws_lambda_alias" "lambda_alias" {
  name             = terraform.workspace
  description      = "Release candidate -"
  function_name    = var.function_name
  function_version = terraform.workspace == "dev" ? "$LATEST" : aws_lambda_function.payload.version
}
```

More information about terraform.workspace syntax can be found in [documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state/workspaces#current-workspace-interpolation).

Comment: Thank you for the hint, Marko! 

What about if I need for the dev version the following syntax to use always $LATEST?

  function_version = var.function_version != "" ? var.function_version : "$LATEST"

Comment: What is the difference between `var.function_version` and `aws_lambda_function.payload.version`? Meaning that one is provided and the other is auto-generated, but what do you need the variable for?

Comment: I need the dev version always to be set to $LATEST not like prod and staging. Because our versions are dev=$LATEST, staging=newer and prod= one version older then staging.

Comment: Thank you, Markus! 

I'm stupid and forgot to try this condition before to ask, sorry. 
Final question. These are 3 workspaces now and the resources are created when the apply is executed. On the second apply from the other Workspace Terraform is trying to create the resources again and returns "resource already exist, duplicated resources are not allowed. I try with count meta-argument and variable type bool with true value but this doesn't work. Any hint? 

Cheers

Comment: Which resource says that?

Comment: I'm receiving the warnings for the aws_iam_role and aws_iam_policy.

Comment: Well, that's a different question. If the answer above solves your issue, please consider accepting it and opening a new issue for the IAM policy/role. But in short, you could just append the workspace name to the policy/role name and that should take care of it.